# pyparsing operatorPrecedence: ability to add parseAction to parentheses blocks

Tags: python, pyparsing, operator-precedence

I have a very simple parser to implement boolean functionality, where I have added classes as parseAction for different operations.

```
parseExpr = pp.operatorPrecedence(term,
           [
              (not_, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, ClassNotOperation),
              (pp.Optional(and_, default="AND"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ClassAndOperation),
              (or_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ClassOrOperation),
           ])
```

This helps me parse following in the correct order

> (A or B) and C

But, is there any way in which I can attach parseActions to parentheses blocks, if I want to add some operation on the block level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using the standard API. If you want to do a special version of `operatorPrecedence` (now renamed to `infixNotation`), copy that routine out of the pyparsing Python code into your local script, and make whatever modifications you want.